# Use Google Game Services to ensure one user per purchase

Tags: android, authentication, google-play

Can I use Google Game Service to store a unique Key created at my backend to this game account to identify NOT the user in particular, but to avoid app-sharing?

Since we allow the users to register anonymously (without entering a username and password), but the users can register later, we need to ensure the users are not able to duplicate valid purchased accounts by creating multiple regular accounts on different anonymous installed apps

The idea is:

1. User purchase an app in app store for lets say 10 bucks
2. User will be asked for google game account when starting the first time
3. My Backend will create a token especially for this user and stores it in the users game service data at google site.
4. When the user will install his app on other devices he needs to choose an account, when the chosen account does contain a valid key (my backend can check) he will have access to the app